# How do I copy 2D CUDA arrays/textures between contexts?

Tags: multi-gpu, cuda-driver, cuda-arrays

Suppose I want to copy some memory between different CUDA contexts (possibly on different devices). The CUDA Driver API [offers me](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM):

- `cuMemcpyPeer` - for plain old device global memory
- `cuMemcpy3DPeer` - for 3D arrays/textures

But there doesn't seem to be a similar API function for 2D arrays. Why? And - what do I do? Should I go through plain global memory buffers in both contexts?

PS - Same question for asynchronous copies; we have the plain and 3D cases covered, but no 2D.